# RateLimiter only works attached to certain methods

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, caching, resilience4j

My method requires two API calls, and is decorated with Spring Boot's `@Cacheable` as well as Resilience4j's `@RateLimiter` ([link to doc](https://resilience4j.readme.io/docs/getting-started-3)):

```
    @Cacheable(value = "getProjectFile")
    @RateLimiter(name = "getProjectFile")
    public Optional<String> getProjectFile(String projectName) {
        return getFileName(projectName).flatMap(this::getProjectFileFromFileName);
    }

    private Optional<String> getFileName(String projectName) {
        String url = getUrlFromProjectName(projectName);
        return Optional.ofNullable(restTemplate.getForObject(url, String.class));
    }

    private Optional<String> getProjectFileFromFileName(String fileName) {
        String url = getUrlFromFileName(fileName);
        return Optional.ofNullable(restTemplate.getForObject(url, String.class));
    }
```

Both annotations work perfectly - *but* the rate limiter turns on even when accessing cached values, slowing down my programme unnecessarily.

To fix this, I tried moving the `@RateLimiter` annotation to `getFileName`, `getProjectFileFromFileName`, or both - but all of a sudden it stops working (the code compiles, but requests are too frequent).

Why does `@RateLimiter` work on the first function, but not the second or third? And how can I get the rate limiter inside the cached function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of Spring AOP annotations don't work when you call a method, which is annotated, locally from the same class (bean), because then the PROXY is bypassed.

`@Cacheable` and  `@RateLimiter` on the same method might not work, because of the Spring AOP Aspect order. See: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.3.15.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-ataspectj-advice-ordering

You can configure the order of the RateLimiter globally, but it might be better to move the method `getFileName` into another Bean und only use `@RateLimiter`.

Comment: This is correct - I resolved the problem by extracting the line that calls getForObject() to another class , and moving @RateLimiter to that extracted method:)